# Merge multi-page html table in one page to save paper

Tags: html, css, html-table, yii2

I have over 40+ rows of html table that span across 2-3 pages. I have only two small columns in the table so I thought of fully occupying the space in the page by merging two page's table data in one page to save paper when printing. Let's say, if the 24th row is last row in first page, I want the 25th row to appear in the second page column (not table column) of the same page as depicted in the screenshot.

I used Yii2 framework's Gridview to render the data. The generated html is as below.

```
<div id="w0" class="grid-view"><div class="summary">Total <b>50</b> items.</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead>
<tr><th>Appt.#</th><th>Patient Name</th><th>User Phone No</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-key="93"><td>1</td><td></td><td>abc</td></tr>
<tr data-key="94"><td>2</td><td></td><td>xyz</td></tr>
.
.
.
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to make this happen automatically when a user prints?

Comment: No required. I'm rendering dedicated page for print so I manipulate it when viewing it in the browser itself.

Comment: Then just make another HTML table for each 24 rows. If you're wondering how to position them once they exist, you could try floating them all.

Comment: That's a challenge. Because, I use a Yii2's GridView to render the dynamic data and table is generated by it and I cannot put new new html table for each 24 rows.  Is it possible to float a single, lengthy table? I'm more into server side scripting side, so if you can share some snippet, it would be great.

Comment: No, you can't split a table with CSS like that.

Comment: You could try a combination of multiple columns (on the page) and the page-break properties (inside the table) but I'm afraid that isn't handled very well by the browsers, and will become very frustrating to implement.

Comment: Maybe you can use Javascript to break the table down into smaller tables after the page is built.

Answer (score 0):

You could try rendering the container using columns, but support is pretty flaky.

```
@media print
{
   #w0
   {
      -webkit-column-count: 3;
      -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
   }
}
```